# Ruby on Rails validation with lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I am changing my validation to adapt them to Rails 5.2 (No strings in if and unless)

I don't know how to translate this (that works fine) one with a lambda:

```
validates :validezElegida, :presence => { :if => 'validez.nil?', message: ". Tienes que seleccionar la duración de la promoción" }
```

I did something like that with no result:

```
  validates :validezElegida, presence: true, unless: -> { validez.nil? }, message: ". Tienes que seleccionar la duración de la promoción"
```

Comment: Wouldn't `if: -> { validez.nil? }` be a closer match for the old one?

Comment: That one works, but I need to provide the message

Answer (score 0):

You can try using message in presence.

```
validates :validezElegida, presence: { message: ". Tienes que seleccionar la duración de la promoción"}, unless: -> { validez.nil? }
```

More information about custom message on rails guides: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message